# Making vertical tabs with two columns and content via Ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, multiple-columns

I am trying to create two column layout with title panels on the left and remote content loaded on the the right column as on the attached picture.

[image]

Content on this picture is loaded via jQuery:
[image: Content on this picture is loaded via jQuery]

Any simple suggestions/examples on how to achieve same results with a two column tab layout?

```
<div class="row table-responsive">
        <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 table-responsive">

            <div class="tab-content" id="accordion1">
              <div class="tab-pane active">
                <div class="sbox c01"> <span class="tab-box-title">Title 1</span><span style="display:none" class="post-des"> 
                  <!--END TEXT FOR BOX 0--> 
                  <!-- START TEXT Right Panel - BOX 0-->
                  <p id="tab1"> </p>
                  </span> </div>
                <!--START TEXT FOR BOX 1--> 
                <!--    END TEXT RIGHT PANEL  - BOX 2-->

                <div> </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Right Panel--> 
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="post-text">
          <div class="process-item delay5 animate fadeInLeft">
            <div class="tab-text" id="tab-text-bkg">
              <h3></h3>
              <p class="font-m detail-post"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Update:
Whenever I split the accordion into 2 columns the content does not load. 
As a temporary solution I created a tab panel and assigned different media queries for the tabs and the accordion, and used 2 different scripts to load the content from the external files. This may not be the most elegant way to do it but for now it seems to be working.
The content in the accordion loads via js:

```
$( "#accordion_post" ).accordion({
collapsible: true, active: false
});

$("#accordion_post").on("click", "dd", function (event) {
 $("div.active").slideToggle("fast");
 $(this).find(".content").slideToggle("fast");
 });

$.post("acc_mobile/_content.html",function(postresult){
$("#pan1").append(postresult);
});

$.post("acc_mobile/_content_4.html",function(postresult){
$("#pan2").append(postresult);
});

$.post("acc_mobile/_content_3.html",function(postresult){
$("#pan3").append(postresult);
});

$.post("acc_mobile/_content_2.html",function(postresult){
$("#pan4").append(postresult);
});
```

Comment: If the content is loaded into the panel in a vertical layout, why can't you load it into the panel on the right the same way? I guess I'm not understanding what you're trying to accomplish, and there is code missing. I don't know how your content is loaded.

Comment: Whenever I split the accordion into 2 columns the content does not load. 
As a temporary solution I created a tab panel and assigned different media queries for the tabs and the accordion, and used 2 different scripts to load the content from the external files. This may not be the most elegant way to do it but for now it seems to be working.
The content in the accordion loads via this scrip: